# LegendMarkerSize: width ignored?

Tags: plotting, legending

The following code fails to set the width of the BarLegend correctly, even though the height is adjusted properly. Why? (I am using Mathematica 11.1)

**Edit:** Minimal code

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 500,  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[ Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {100, 400}]]
```

Result:

[image: The width of the BarLegend is not set properly.]

Full code:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
SetOptions[Plot, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Sans 10", FontSize -> 45}];
SetOptions[Plot, AxesLabel -> {Style[FontFamily -> "LM Sans 10", FontSize -> 45]}];

iSize = 500; pSize = 2.5; maxRec = 2; 
prob1 = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -pSize, pSize}, {y, -pSize, pSize},
            ImageSize -> iSize,
            MaxRecursion -> maxRec,
            Axes -> True, ClippingStyle -> Automatic,
            FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "LM Sans 10", FontSize -> 25 (iSize/1000)],
            AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontFamily -> "LM Sans 10", FontSize -> 35 (iSize/1000)],
                          Style["y", FontFamily -> "LM Sans 10", FontSize -> 35 (iSize/1000)]},
            PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,
                                     LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Sans 10", FontSize -> 45 (iSize/1000)},
                                     LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 0.9 iSize}],
            ColorFunction -> "LightTemperatureMap"]
```

Comment: Please post the *minimal* code that illustrates your problem.  Do we need to know the name of the plot?  Axes label?, MaxRecursion? Notebook directory?  Color scheme?  etc. etc.?  Of course not.  This suffices:  `ContourPlot[
 x^2 + y^2, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 25}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 500}]]`

Comment: I just thought the context might be relevant, since I am adjusting quite a few parameters of the plot. Find the minimal code in an edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution; the `Automatic` keyword somehow overrides the width settings. This code works:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 500, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {0, 10}}, LegendMarkerSize -> {80, 500}]]
```

Output:[image]